# webpack: Critical dependency message

Tags: webpack

I'm getting this error when I load my components:

> ./~/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js
>   5889:15-36 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

Anyone could help out to figure out what does it mean?

Comment: Angular 2? or Angular 4?  I just updated from 2 to 4 and started getting this warning.  Have you figured out what's causing this yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got my issue nailed down.  Perhaps you're experiencing the same thing.
In Angular 2.x I had

```
new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
    // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
    /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
    root('./app'), // location of your src
    {} // a map of your routes
)
```

Now in Angular 4.x it changes to...

```
new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
        /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/,
        root('./app'),
        {}
)
```

Per this post https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11580

Comment: @Landeeyo In the plugins section of your webpack config

Answer (score 2):

I got the same kind of message with typescript.js.

**[...]/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js 5123:41-60
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression**

I understand that it have something to do with typescript.js file and the dynamic require written at line 5123 :

```js
return { module: require(modulePath), modulePath: modulePath, error: undefined };
```

I tried many times but I really don't know how to use the ContextReplacementPlugin to avoid this warning.

The warning appear when I use transpile from the typescript module

```js
import { transpile } from 'typescript';
```

Does anyone have the same problem?